# How should I log the user in based on a token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I have users (a model), each with authorizations (a related model) to one oauth system or another (facebook for example).

I want a user to be able to login using information passed in the query string (email & token hash). How can I do this? I am using devise and omniauth.

For instance:

http://site.com/login?email=asdfdsafas&token_hash=43879237498237492347

Rather than passing a username & password or auth token.

Comment: like a sign in with facebook button?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Railscasts episode

http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password

You can use this functionality, with just a little bit of manipulation, to create a secure way of accomplishing what you're trying to do.